# How to add customization in Knowledge article expiration View in Dynamics CRM

Tags: calendar, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have added out of the box Calendar view in my Knowledge article table and views but it is not as user friendly and customizable as i wanted it to be.
I want to add on each day total number of articles expired.